# How to set name and id on a TR element?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to access `TR` elements through `firstChild` or `lastChild` object, however using `ID` or `Name` property doesn't seem to be working:

https://jsfiddle.net/7594v0kg/13/

```
<html>
<body>
<table id="tbl">
<tr name="first" id="first">
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
</tr>
<tr name="second">
    <td>789</td>
    <td>987</td>
</tr>
</table>
<span id="out"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript code:

```
var elt=document.getElementById("tbl")
var out=document.getElementById("out")
out.innerHTML="name="+ +elt.firstChild.name+",id="+elt.firstChild.id
```

the output is:

```
123 456
789 987
name=NaN,id=undefined
```

How should I modify my code to access the elements by `id` or `name`? This is needed to implement a deleting process but only children labeled with some values should remain.

JSFildle is provided
https://jsfiddle.net/7594v0kg/13/

Comment: Name attribute is valid only for form control elements and window objects. `firstChild`finds also textnodes.

Comment: if you `console.log(elt.firstChild)` you will see it is #text, also you will see the browser has probably added a `tbody `

Comment: In addition to Niet's correct answer below, it's worth noting that `name` is not a valid attribute for an `<hr>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var elt=document.getElementById("tbl")
var out=document.getElementById("out")
out.innerHTML="name="+elt.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.getAttribute("name")+
",id="+elt.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.getAttribute("id")
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
<tr name="first" id="first">
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
</tr>
<tr name="second">
    <td>789</td>
    <td>987</td>
</tr>
</table>
<span id="out"></span>
```

Hope this will helps you..:)

Answer (score 2):

It is not actually valid to have `<table><tr>`. The browser is silently correcting your invalid HTML to `<table><tbody><tr>`. You will notice this if you try `elt.children[0].nodeName`.

Note also that the whitespace between elements in your code counts as the `firstChild` - this is why I used `children[0]` above.

Comment: It would probably be more idiomatic to use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild).

Comment: Thanks. Actually, what I need to delete is all `tbody` children while leaving the header intact, so your answer was very helpful rewrite all my code

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend please try to do with jquery plugin.

```
out.innerHTML="name="+$(elt).find('tr:first td:first').text()+",id="+$(elt).find('tr:first td:last').text();
```

This is the solution I found. Try it once in your given fiddle.

```js
var elt=document.getElementById("tbl")
var out=document.getElementById("out")

out.innerHTML="name="+$(elt).find('tr:first td:first').text()+",id="+$(elt).find('tr:first td:last').text();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<table id="tbl">
<tr name="first" id="first">
    <td>123</td>
    <td>456</td>
</tr>
<tr name="second">
    <td>789</td>
    <td>987</td>
</tr>
</table>
<span id="out"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am avoiding JQuery because it consumes a lot of resources

Comment: Okay. I'll try with pure javascript and let you know.